# Wiring an ECM to AC power

Tags: wiring, hvac

I'm trying to wire a motor to work on 120v ac power. I accidentally bought an EC motor, because the price was so low, and cant find any sort of wire diagram for it

From research, I found that all of them have a separate connector for ac power, but i cant find it. I plan on adding a switch and speed controller.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So, what is the question? Can you post a picture of the other label on the motor? The picture you posted has no useful information about the motor.

Comment: The white plug on the side of the motor that is where your power goes. With what looks like 12? Connections you probably got a multiphase motor. What is the model # ?

Comment: According to the label, the motor is single phase. Model #447PWAAD. The 12pin connector is usually paired with a 5 pin connector for power, which I cant find anywhere on the motor

Comment: This motor is probably repackaged by US Motor for some OEM application and somebody found a pallet of them for cheap because the OEM isn't using them anymore. You'll likely need to get a look inside the black box in order to figure out the wiring scheme. There is likely Line, neutral, ground, and five or more control wires that need 24V to run this motor in it's various modes.

Comment: Since it is single phase I would look up 12 wire motor configuration 115v would be the low voltage configuration because of the / then 208-277 high voltage. I have never seen a 12 wire single phase but have seen 12 wire 3 phase they are normal for using delta start Wye run type setups. There must be a nema configuration out there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

ECM means "electronically commutated motor." Fundamentally it is likely a brushless DC (BLDC) motor. Commutation is the fancy name for the process of moving the magnetic fields in sync with the motion of the rotor in order to sustain motion. This type of motor won't run without an electronic controller. Controllers are, to some degree, designed to work with particular motors depending on maximum voltage, current, speed, load, acceleration profile -- any given speed controller might or might not perform well, or at all, with a given motor.

The short answer is this: one doesn't wire an ECM motor to AC power. The AC power goes only to the motor controller; the motor controller outputs go to the ECM motor's windings. There are likely to be position sensors built into the motor which provide feedback to the controller as well.

All this said, though.. it's interesting that the motor would have mains voltages marked on it. This motor may have a built-in controller -- if so a few of the pins in the connector are probably for mains supply while the others are for logic signals that tell the controller what to do.

Comment: Ive gotten that far in my research. The controller is housed in the black box on the bottom of the motor. All the ECM's I've seen have a 16ish pin connector and a separate 5 pin connector for ac power, but this one only has one 12pin connector